# TFS Web Packaging Package Structure

Tags: build-automation, setup-deployment

I've found an issue in one of our build definitions in TFS 2010.
It's actually not really an issue because it still works but I'm wondering... why does it still work?

If you choose "Edit build definition" in Visual Studio and choose the tab "Process", you can set the "Web Packages" section. If you add a new member to the collection, you can choose "Package structure" under the section "Package Definition". If you add a new member there, you can choose the path to a project folder.

In the current build definition some of these members references a project from 2 sprints ago (!). But why does this work? The project still compiles and no one ever noticed it... 
What does this setting actually do?

Comment: The Parameters you are referring to are not standard: They can only be part of a customized build process template. Adding them must have happened as described here http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx by someone you might want to find & ask. Alternatively, in order to get help from SO, you will have to post details on how this is implemented.